# Is there a way to know the name of a calling function in PL/PgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

When I call a PL/PgSQL function (not a trigger) from another such function, is it possible to know the name or some kind of ID of a calling function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as close as you will get, and it won't work in nested calls.

```
SELECT current_query();
```

You might want to email pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org with a feature request, including the use case you have for wanting to know this information.

Comment: This gives me a full text of the calling query. Thanks!